# Как правильно писать DAO ?

Tags: java-ee, hibernate, java, база-данных

Здравствуйте, я хотел бы узнать как профессионально написать доступ к БД.

В интернете видел такие указания.

1.Написать интерфейс

```
public interface MyObjDAO {
    public void save(MyObj object);
    public MyObj getById(int id);
    ...
}
```

2.Написать реализацию. Я использую библиотеку Hibernate.

```
public class HibernateAccess implements MyObjDAO{

    @Override
    public void save(MyObj object) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

        Session s = factory.openSession();
        s.beginTransaction();
        s.save(object);
        s.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    @Override
    public MyObj getById(int id){
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        .....
        .....
    }
}
```

У меня такие вопросы:

1. Если я использую доступ к БД в WEB приложении (в котором одновременно несколько пользователей потребует доступ), нужно ли синхронизировать методы доступа ?
2. Правильно ли создавать конфигурацию и билдер библиотеки Hibernate в методах доступа(или может быть правильно создать класс синглтон для выдачи сессии)
3. Ну и вообще хотелось бы послушать мнение людей с опытом, как это делать правильно.

Я прошу прощения за ламерские вопросы, но я не смог найти в интернете однозначного ответа.

---

UPD.
Итак, ответ на мой вопрос номер 2

> SessionFactory is an extremely
> expensive process which involves
> parsing hibernate
> configuration/mapping properties and
> creating database connection pool
> .Creating a database connection pool
> requires establishing database
> connections (i.e creating Connection
> objects) which has overhead due to the
> time taken to locate the DB server ,
> establish a communication channel and
> exchange information to do
> authentication.
>
> So if you create a SessionFactory for
> every request , it implies that you
> are not using database connection pool
> to serve your request .You have to
> setup a new connection by the above
> overheaded process for every request
> instead of just getting the opened
> connection from the database
> connection pool.

Таким образом SessionFactory должен быть 1 на приложение.

---

UPD2 По поводу синхронизации. SessionFactory полностью синхронизирован. А саму сессию в нужно создавать в каждом потоке независимо.

---

UPD3 Если кому интересно. Для получения объекта сессии рекомендуют использовать паттерн [Open Session in View](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView), который, по сути, представляет сервлет-фильтр, открывающий сессию и контролирующий комит транзакции для всех остальных сервлетов. Таким образом легко избегается LazyInitializationException. Но мне такой вариант не нравится, так как сессии создаются для **всех** сервлетов, таким образом при открытии одной страницы происходит многократное открытие-закрытие сессии даже для тех сервлетов, которые не имеют отношения к БД.

---

UPD4 Попал случайно на интересную статью [Не повторяйте DAO!](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-genericdao/), но там она вперемешку со спрингом, хотя сама идея дженерик дао мне нравится!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

мы в своих приложениях уже длительное время используем примерно следующую иерархию обьектов для реализации работы с СУБД:

1) иерархия для `entities` - каждая ентити описывает одну таблицу, у них есть общий предок для того чтоб можно было легко идентифицировать все обьекты)+ добавить какой-то общий функционал (хотя бы метод toString() переопределить ). Если же дополнительного функционала не надо то можно использовать интерфейс:

```
abstract class ABaseDaoEntity {
}

class EntityA extends ABaseDaoEntity {
    private String id;

    // getters,setters    
}

class EntityB extends ABaseDaoEntity {
    private String name;
    private String userId;

    // getters,setters
}
```

2) любые воспомагательные классы (в данном случае только свой тип ошибки):

```
class DaoException extends Exception {
}
```

3) иерархия DAO: интерфейс с общими методами (опционально добавляется к интерфейсу конкретного DAO):

```
interface IDao<T extends ABaseDaoEntity> {

    // get by id
    void get(T entity) throws DaoException;
    T create(T entity) throws DaoException;
    void update(T entity) throws DaoException;
    void delete(T entity) throws DaoException;
}
```

4) иерархия DAO: общий абстрактный класс: нужен для того чтоб добавить общий функционал всем дао (в вашем случае только ссылка на обьект `session factory`), помимо этого здесь же должны быть реализации методов IDao если этот код является универсальным для любой `entity`. При использовании фреймворков зачастую так и есть как минимум для методов: `create`, `update`, `delete`

```
abstract class ABaseDao<T extends ABaseDaoEntity> implements IDao<T> {
    private SessionFactory factory;

    public ABaseDao(SessionFactory factory) {
        setFactory(factory);
    }

    protected SessionFactory getFactory() {
        return factory;
    }
    protected void setFactory(SessionFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    // here we may add implementation for common IDao methods
    // (if possible of course, - just in case implementation is the same for all types of entities)
}
```

5) иерархия DAO: интерфейсы дао обьектов, по сути здесь необходимо обьявлять только методы find, т.к. добавить остальные можно просто добавив наследование от интерфейса IDao (очевидно что только при необходимости):

```
// dao with inheritance from IDao
interface IEntityADao extends IDao<EntityA> {

    List<EntityA> findAll() throws DaoException;
}

// dao without inheritance from IDao
interface IEntityBDao {

    // find entity by name and user id
    EntityB get(String name, String userId) throws DaoException;

    List<EntityB> findAll() throws DaoException;
}
```

6) иерархия DAO: примеры имплементаций DAO:

```
// concrete dao for EntityA
class EntityADao extends ABaseDao<EntityA> implements IEntityADao {

    public EntityADao(SessionFactory factory) {
        super(factory);
    }

    // implementations of the ABase DAO methods (required only)

    // implementations of the EntityA DAO methods

}

// concrete dao for EntityB
class EntityBDao extends ABaseDao<EntityB> implements IEntityBDao {

    public EntityBDao(SessionFactory factory) {
        super(factory);
    }

    // implementations of the EntityB DAO methods

}
```

p.s упустил важную деталь:

7) DAO factory: нужны для того чтоб получать доступ к конкретному DAO обьекту:

```
interface IDaoFactory {
  IEntityADao getEntityADao();
  IEntityBDao getEntityBDao();
}
class DaoFactory implements IDaoFactory {
  // implementations of all methods
}
```

p.s. если DAO stateless обьекты (по функционалу) - можно при каждом вызове геттера их создавать, если же `statefull`, то можно создать их при создании обьекта DaoFactory а потом уже возвращать ссылки на обьекты (можно применить lazy loading)

8) IDaoFactoryBean, DaoFactoryBean - интерфейс (опционально) и имплементация бина, который собственно и отвечает за создание и предоставление доступа к `DAOFactory`. это должна быть EJB компонента, singleton

```
interface IDaoFactoryBean {
    IDaoFactory getDaoFactory();
}
```

p.s. если создание session factory процес сложный или есть необходимость часто его менять то лучше создание этого обьекта вынести в отдельный singleton ejb. в этом случае бин DaoFactoryBean можно сделать stateless если `DaoFactory` тоже является stateless (имеется в виду не ejb stateless a по функционалу)

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ! Очень познавательно. Надо переварить коннекторое время :)